# wordpress permalinks not working - htaccess seems ok but getting 404 error on pages

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I updated the permalink structure to /%postname%/ and this updated my .htaccess with:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But I still get 404 errors on the pages. Are there any other settings that I need to change?

Edit: if it helps the apache log seems to be looking directly in the permalinked folder. I.e.:

```
[Wed Oct 16 11:12:32 2013] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/exampledomain/news, referer: http://exampledomain.com/
```

Comment: Maybe you should accept a answer.

Comment: Check this article for your issue. https://www.phparticles.com/wordpress/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 85):

**For other people landing on this page -** 
Another issue could be (If you are using Apache as your web server) is your httpd.conf or your sites-available/sitename.conf file needs editing.

Your web directory will need to allow the .htaccess file to override it's settings.

look for your web dir in the file - it will be in the bulk of the conf file or segregated into a VirtualHost section.

```
<Directory /path/to/site>
     #add the following setting to allow .htaccess in your web dir to work
     AllowOverride FileInfo

     #other settings ---

</Directory>
```

This will allow you to set up WordPress URLs however you want, within WordPress.

***Edited - Thank You nietonfir For update. Use the least amount of privilege at first. If this doesn't work then replace `AllowOverride FileInfo` with `AllowOverride All`

Comment: This is partially correct. `AllowOverride FileInfo` is usually enough, see the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride). You should always strive for the principle of least privilege.

Comment: This looks like it might solve my problem; however, what should I do if neither httpd.conf or sites-available/sitename.conf are present?

Comment: @ Time4Tea - does your web dir have a .../sites-available/default file in it? Configs should be there.

Answer (score 61):

There can be multiple things preventing the rewrite rule from working. My ubuntu server needed 3 things changed to get permalinks working.

In newer versions of apache2, you need to enable the module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You may also need to modify the apache2.conf file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Change your web directory override rule to **AllowOverride All**.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that, restart the service again.

The .htaccess file in the WordPress install directory needs to be owned or readable/modifiable by the webserver.

This can be accomplished by changing owner to www-data (usually the webserver user), or changing permissions.

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/wordpress-install/.htaccess
```

OR

```
sudo chmod 664 /var/www/wordpress-install/.htaccess
```

Login to your Wordpress admin backend and save the permalink settings, and they should hopefully be working.

Comment: Props for the very complete answer!

Comment: Had to document the crazyness I went through just for my future self!

Comment: In my case was the `AllowOverride All` clause which was failing

Comment: This answer helps me a lot.

Comment: This is the best answer. The change to the apache2.conf file worked for me as well. Many thanks!

Comment: This was the only thing what helped me! Thanks, this should be marked as answer.

Comment: What if even this doesn't help? I have tried everything mentioned here, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Most useful answer for the question

Comment: thank you very much. few answers mentioned that apache2's rewrite mod is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 32):

This is now solved. I hadn't enabled mod_rewrite. So I did this:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
$ service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
```

Comment: In fact that solved my problem. I thought the AllowOverride was the issue.

Comment: Thank you...I missed the same thing :):)

Comment: In my situation, this and `AllowOverride FileInfo` were necessary in order for it to work.

Answer (score 14):

You would want to tell apache to follow your .htaccess file. You can do this by editing the apache.conf file

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache.conf
```

Scroll down to the line 
By default it will be:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

change the value of AllowOverride to All so now it becomes:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Press ctrl+x and press y to save the configuration file. In order to make this changes to server first enable the mod_rewrite by.

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And then restart the server

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Done!

Source: https://www.wst.space/riddling-with-wordpress-permalink-setup-issues/

Answer (score 6):

use below .htaccess code, just put your project name (which is in www directory) in below code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project_name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was facing with the same problem and had one more thing to look for.

Here is what you need to do for wordpress permalinks work properly:

1. Make sure you have the proper permission modes for files and folders in your wordpress directory:
   `sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +`
   `sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`
2. For permalink structure make sure `mode_rewrite` is enabled in apache:
   `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
   `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to check if this describes your problem:

- htaccess and mod_rewrite are set up correctly
- **404 error on some permalinks but not others**

Ensure that there are no existing .php files or directories in the same folder as your Wordpress install with names matching a Wordpress permalink.

For example, if you have the following Wordpress page permalinks:

```
 example.com/name_one/
 example.com/name_two/
```

and the directory containing your Wordpress install includes the following file:

```
 name_one.php
```

then this will be the result:

- http://example.com/name_two/ – this permalink will work
- http://example.com/name_one/ – this permalink will **NOT** work

More importantly, the second URL *will give a 404 instead of running name_one.php*, meaning this problem is hard to diagnose, as it can give the same symptoms as an incorrectly written .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ***setting up a new or cloned site*** on ubuntu, remember to symlink the site configuration file e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-file.conf` to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder so apache loads it.

---

Just run: `sudo a2ensite your-file.conf`, then `sudo service apache2 reload`.

`sudo a2dissite your-file.conf` to remove symlink i.e. disable config.

Answer (score 0):

**Users of WAMP (Windows)**: Some versions of WAMP (all versions?) do not enable mod_rewrite or permit following SymLinks by default. To enable the required functionality navigate to the `apache/conf/httpd.conf file`, open with a text editor and uncomment the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite`.so (i.e., delete the hash/pound sign at the front of the line). Then further down in the same file there is a section that starts with the line "**Options FollowSymlinks**". Change the second line in that section from "`AllowOverride none`" to `AllowOverride all`. Save edited httpd.conf and restart all WAMP modules. Your permalinks should now work.

[For more details, Fixing Permalink Problems](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility: I just updated my macOS which *always* screws up the Apache config file. Among other things, I also had to re-enable the `mod_rewrite` module. Find the line that says,

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

And remove the hash so it says,

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, double check no errors in **Directory** in VirtualHost, Apache wont warn you if you input an incorrect directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/site/wordpress>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/site/wordpress/wp-content>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```