# How do I trace permalink errors in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Yesterday I updated ssl certificate. The process was a mess (probably because my error http and https got mixed in certbot update causing ssl errors). Finally I realized that I had both https and http in 000-default-le-ssl.conf and removed port 80 section. The certificate updated finished succesfully.

Now I can't get permalink work in pretty link: /%postname%/
E.g: I want to use https://fruity/cart instead of https://fruity.co.il/?page_id=15.

.htacess is generated by wordpress:

```
# ההוראות (שורות) בין `BEGIN WordPress` לבין END WordPress` הן
# שנוצר באופן דינמי, ויש לשנות אותן רק באמצעות פילטרים של וורדפרס.
# כל שינוי בהוראות בין סממנים אלה ידרס.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

apachectl -M indicates that rewrite_module is loaded.
No errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

What to do next to solve it?

Thank in advance.

Comment: In dashboard go to `settings > permalinks` change it to whatever you want and save

Comment: Thanks, @Fresz. I did that. It doesn't help. I get 404 response to pages with postname.

Comment: After changing back permalink to simple links with id=## the pages are found.

Comment: Started in wordpress version 5.4.1. Reverting to 5.3.3 didn't help.

Comment: found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400749/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-htaccess-seems-ok-but-getting-404-error-on-pa